# Verificar se delta é menor que zero (Fórmula de Bhaskara)

Tags: python

Basicamente o que eu preciso é se delta for maior que 0 deveria parar e mostrar uma mensagem de "Não existe raiz", porém não estou conseguindo botar o: `D < 0`  `print('Não existe raízes')`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```py
def raizes(a, b, c):
    D = (b**2 - 4*a*c)
    x1 = (-b + D**(1/2)) / (2*a)
    x2 = (-b - D**(1/2)) / (2*a)

    print('\nValor de x1: {0}'.format(x1))
    print('Valor de x2: {0}'.format(x2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print('Calculando as raízes de uma equação de 2º grau\n')
        a = float(input('Entre com o valor de a: '))
        b = float(input('Entre com o valor de b: '))
        c = float(input('Entre com o valor de c: '))
        raizes(a,b,c)
        
                
        continua = input('Deseja sair? Digite q ou Enter para novo cálculo:')
        if (continua == 'q'):
            break
```

Comment: Favor formatar o código. E colocar o que vc já tentou.

Comment: Tente: `if D < 0: print('Não existe raízes') else: ...`

Comment: Essa mensagem do `continua = input(...)` tá confusa. Dá a entender que digitando 'q' ou 'Enter' o programa vai continuar rodando

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esta questão deves prestar atenção à algumas coisas, tais como:

1. Saber como capturar os valores dos **coeficientes**;
2. Calcular o valor de **delta** e, também, as **raízes**;
3. Exibir corretamente o retorno da função - de acordo com suas restrições;
4. Implementar um **laço** para reexecutar o código, caso o usuário desejar.

Pondo em prática esta lógica, implementei o seguinte código:

```
def raizes(a, b, c):
    d = ((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))
    if d < 0:
        msg = 'Não existe raízes Reais!'
        return msg
    else:
        x1 = round(((-b + (d ** (1 / 2))) / (2 * a)), 1)
        x2 = round(((-b - (d ** (1 / 2))) / (2 * a)), 1)

        if x1 == -0.0:
            x1 = 0
        if x2 == -0.0:
            x2 = 0

        menor = x1
        if x2 < x1:
            maior = x1
            menor = x2
        else:
            maior = x2

        if d == 0:
            msg = f'Duas raízes Reais iguais: x1 = {menor} e x2 = {maior}'
            return msg
        else:
            msg = f'Duas raízes Reais diferentes: x1 = {menor} e x2 = {maior}'
            return msg


while True:
    coef_A, coef_B, coef_C = list(map(float, input('Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C": ').split()))

    print(raizes(coef_A, coef_B, coef_C))

    resp = input('Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]: ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!')
        resp = input('Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]: ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Neste momento devemos digitar os **3** coeficientes da referida equação, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Neste momento os valores digitados são capturados e enviados como parâmetros para a função **raizes(a, b, c)**. Chegando lá será calculado o valor de delta - *d*. Uma vez tendo o resultado do delta, será verificado se este valor é menor que **0**. Caso este valor seja de fato **menor que 0** o retorno da função será: `"Não existe raízes reais"`. Caso este valor seja diferente de **0** o fluxo do código será desviado para o bloco **else**.

Chegando lá, serão calculadas as raízes da função quadrática.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

Segundo o **[Teorema Fundamental da Álgebra](https://blog.estrategiavestibulares.com.br/teorema-fundamental-da-algebra/)**,***“Todo polinômio não constante de grau n possui n raízes complexas, não necessariamente todas distintas”.***

Resumindo: **qualquer função quadrática sempre terá 2 raízes**, podendo ser: **2 raízes REAIS iguais ou 2 raízes REAIS diferentes ou 2 raízes IMAGINÁRIAS diferentes**

Pois bem, neste momento será verificado se o valor de delta - **d** - é igual a **0**, ou melhor, se **d == 0**. Caso positivo, a função quadrática terá duas raízes reais iguais, isto é **x1 == x2**. Caso contrário, a função quadrática terá duas raízes reais diferentes, ou seja, **x1 != x2**

Depois de ter exibido o resultado dos cálculos recebermos a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **S**, para realizar novo cálculo ou **N** para encerrar a execução do código.

**Vamos testar o código?**

**Exemplo 1:**

Calcule as raízes da função quadrática **x² - 3x + 2**.

Neste momento executamos o código e, quando recebermos a mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Devemos digitar...

```
1 -3 2
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.

Neste momento o código realizará os cálculos e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
Duas raízes Reais diferentes: x1 = 1.0 e x2 = 2.0
Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:
```

Se desejarmos realizar novo cálculo basta pressionarmos a letra **S**. Caso contrário, devemos pressionar a letra **N**.

**Exemplo 2**

Calcule as raízes da função quadrática **-3x² + 6**.

**Observação:** Nesta função não temos o **coeficiente de B**. Neste caso digitaremos **0** para o valor do coeficiente de "B".

Então, executamos o código e, quando recebermos a mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Devemos digitar...

```
-3 0 6
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.
Neste momento o código realizará os cálculos e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
Duas raízes Reais diferentes: x1 = -1.4 e x2 = 1.4
Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:
```

**Exemplo 3**

Calcule as raízes da função quadrática **x - 2x²**.

**Observação:** Nesta função temos a ordem dos termos trocada. Nesta questão o **A == -2**, o **B == 1** e **C == 0**.

Então, executamos o código e, quando recebermos a mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Devemos digitar...

```
-2 1 0
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.
Neste momento o código realizará os cálculos e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
Duas raízes Reais diferentes: x1 = 0 e x2 = 0.5
Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:
```

**Exemplo 4**

Calcule as raízes reais da função quadrática **x² + 4x + 5**.

Então, executamos o código e, quando recebermos a mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Devemos digitar...

```
1 4 5
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.
Neste momento o código realizará os cálculos e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
Não existe raízes Reais!
Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:
```

**Exemplo 5**

Calcule as raízes reais da função quadrática **x² + 4x + 4**.

Então, executamos o código e, quando recebermos a mensagem: `Coeficientes "A", "B" e "C":` . Devemos digitar...

```
1 4 4
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.
Neste momento o código realizará os cálculos e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
Duas raízes Reais iguais: x1 = -2.0 e x2 = -2.0
Desejas realizar novo cálculo? [S/N]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu explicitaria que não tem raizes reais pois podem existir raízes imaginárias:

```
def raizes(a, b, c):
    D = (b**2 - 4*a*c)
    if D < 0:
        print('Não existem raízes reais')
    else:
         x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
         x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
         print('\nValor de x1: {0}'.format(x1))
         print('Valor de x2: {0}'.format(x2))
```

Answer (score 0):

É só usar `if`/`else`:

```
from math import sqrt

def raizes(a, b, c):
    delta = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
    if delta < 0:
        print('Não existem raízes reais')
    else:
        dois_a = 2 * a
        if delta == 0:
            print(f'Raiz: {-b / dois_a }')
        else:
            raiz_delta = sqrt(delta)
            x1 = -b + raiz_delta / dois_a
            x2 = -b - raiz_delta / dois_a
            print(f'Valor de x1: {x1}')
            print(f'Valor de x2: {x2}')
```

Também mudei algumas coisas.

Se o delta é zero, só existe uma raiz (tecnicamente, são "2 raízes iguais", mas enfim), e nesse caso você não precisa calcular a raiz quadrada (pois a raiz quadrada de zero é zero) e nem calcular 2 raízes (as 2 contas darão o mesmo resultado). Então nesse caso você pode imprimir apenas uma raiz.

Somente se o delta é maior que zero, aí sim eu calculo a raiz, e faço isso somente uma vez, guardando o resultado em uma variável - engraçado que muitas vezes as pessoas criam variáveis sem necessidade, mas neste caso em que há ganho (pois só preciso calcular a raiz uma vez), muitos preferem refazer o cálculo em vez de fazê-lo uma vez só e guardar em uma variável (claro que a diferença de desempenho será imperceptível, foi só uma observação).

Answer (score 0):

Se precisa fazer uma comparação com o valor de delta antes de mostrar ou não as raízes, separe o cálculo do delta do cálculo das raízes.

```
delta  = lambda a, b, c: b**2 - 4*a*c
bhaskara = lambda a, b, delta: (
                                (-b + delta**(1/2)) / (2*a), 
                                (-b - delta**(1/2)) / (2*a)   )

def prompt(frase):  
    try: return float(input(frase))
    except: return prompt(frase)

frases = [f'Entre com o valor de {e}:' for e in ['a','b','c'] ]
continua = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while continua != 'q':
        print('Calculando as raízes de uma equação de 2º grau\n')
        cf = [prompt(f) for f in frases] 
        d = delta(cf[0], cf[1], cf[2])        
        if d < 0:
           print('Não existem raízes reais.')
        else:          
          print("\n".join(
            [ f'Valor de x{e[0] + 1}: {e[1]}' for e in enumerate(bhaskara(cf[0], cf[1], d))]
          ))
        continua = input('\nPressione <Enter> para continuar ou "p" para sair.').lower()
```

Resultado:

```
Calculando as raízes de uma equação de 2º grau

Entre com o valor de a:1
Entre com o valor de b:0
Entre com o valor de c:-1
Valor de x1: 1.0
Valor de x2: -1.0

Pressione <Enter> para continuar ou "p" para sair.
```

Teste o exemplo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HardtofindThornyScreencast)

Leitura adicional:

- [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Erros e exceções](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/errors.html)
- [Expressões lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)
- [Mais ferramentas de controle de fluxo](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)